# Using a p12 file without a password in Java

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

Try as I might, I can't figure out how to use a **.p12** file without a password in Java.  I've tried setting `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` to `""` but whatever I do I get the following SSL error:

> HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

All my googling would suggest that the sun implementation will not allow an empty password and of course the keytool won't let you import any certificate without a password for the store.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sun Java KeyManagerFactory and null passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814048/sun-java-keymanagerfactory-and-null-passwords)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Sun API seems to require a password, so you will instead need to add a password to your `.p12` file.

[This page](http://readpaul.com/blog/1620.html) says that you can do this with `openssl` by converting the `.p12` to a `.pem`, then converting back to a `.p12` (but I have not tried it):

```
open­ssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out temp.pem -passin pass: -passout pass:temppassword
open­ssl pkcs12 -export -in temp.pem -out cert-final.p12 -passin pass:temppassword -passout pass:newpa­ssword
rm -f temp.pem
```

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814048/sun-java-keymanagerfactory-and-null-passwords).

Comment: I've copied your command and spent like 15 minutes trying to figure out why it didn't work until I noticed all minuses look weird and replaced them...

Comment: Good catch - for some reason they seem to have turned into en-dashes (U+2013). Now hopefully fixed.