# Unable to generate JKS file using keytool command and running into keytool error

Tags: ssl, openssl, private-key, keytool, jks

I am trying to create a JKS file from existing private key and certificate and currently following the steps mentioned in [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/06/13/how-to-keystore-creating-jks-file-from-existing-private-key-and-certificate/) documentation.

I was able to generate PKCS12 file using the private key (which is `myrhelserver_cpy_dot_com.key` ) and CA signed certificate (which is `CertificateBundle1.pem`) as shown below:

```
[tan@myrhelserver cert_related]$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in CertificateBundle1.pem -inkey myrhelserver_cpy_dot_com.key -certfile CertificateBundle1.pem -out activemq_p_keystore.p12
Enter Export Password:
Verifying - Enter Export Password:
```

I pressed `Enter` key when it asked me to `Enter Export Password` and `Verifying – Enter Export Password`. After this I saw `activemq_p_keystore.p12` generated inside the directory as shown in the `ls` command below.

```
[tan@myrhelserver cert_related]$ ls
activemq_p_keystore.p12   CertificateBundle1.pem  myrhelserver_cpy_dot_com.key
```

After this I ran the `keytool` command as mentioned in the Step 2 of the documentation - which is asking me to generate the JKS file in the following manner:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore testkeystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore wso2carbon.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

Here is my actual command :

```
[tan@myrhelserver cert_related]$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore activemq_p_keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore wso2carbon.jks -deststoretype JKS
Importing keystore activemq_p_keystore.p12 to wso2carbon.jks...
Enter destination keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
They don't match. Try again
Enter destination keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
Enter source keystore password:
 
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
* The integrity of the information stored in the srckeystore*
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
* you must provide the srckeystore password.                *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
 
keytool error: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input
```

It’s asking for so many passwords as you can see above. So I did the following:

For `Enter destination keystore password:` and `Re-enter new password:` I entered nothing and pressed `Enter` key. It then asked me for `Enter destination keystore password:` and then `Re-enter new password:` and `Enter source keystore password:`
“. I was lost after this.

What am I doing wrong here? Should I be creating new password at any of the steps above?

Comment: This seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904657/using-a-p12-file-without-a-password-in-java

Comment: The above post is for java related questions but I tried to look at the `This Page` link which is not working anymore and other links are not much helpful.