# what is it that I get in java from Azure keyvault certificate

Tags: java, azure, certificate, keystore, azure-keyvault

Certificate is created in Azure KeyVault. I will need to download the public and private key from it.

When creating certificate in Azure, there are two options for the content:pkcs12 and pem

When content type is PEM, I can get the private key and convert it to RSA PrivateKey.

When content type is PKCS12, I am not sure what it is.

```
 //when certificate is created with pkcs12 format, downloadedPK doesn't have any -----BEGIN * KEY-----
 //It's readable format similar to private key/certificate inside .pem file but without any "-----BEGIN *----- "
```

Here is my code:

```
        ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .tenantId(tenantId)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .build();

        CertificateClient certificateClient = new CertificateClientBuilder()
                .vaultUrl(vaultUri)
                .credential(credential)
                .buildClient();

        SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
                .vaultUrl(vaultUri)
                .credential(credential)
                .buildClient();

        // Retrieving certificate
        KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy certificateWithPolicy = certificateClient.getCertificate(alias);

        // Retrieving secrete for private key
        KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.getSecret(alias, certificateWithPolicy.getProperties().getVersion());
        
        String downloadedPK = secret.getValue();
        String privateKeyType = secret.getProperties().getContentType();

        byte[] rawPrivateKey = null;

            //when certificate is created with pem format, downloadedPK has both private and certificate sections
            //needs to extract the raw Private Key
            if ("application/x-pem-file".equalsIgnoreCase(privateKeyType)) {
                /*
                -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
                -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
                -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                -----END CERTIFICATE-----
                 */
                int endIndex = downloadedPK.indexOf("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----");
                String str1 = downloadedPK.substring(0, endIndex);

                privateKeyContent = str1.replaceAll("\\n", "").replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
            }

            //when certificate is created with pkcs12 format, downloadedPK doesn't have any -----BEGIN * KEY-----
            //It's readable format similar to private key/certificate inside .pem file but without any "-----BEGIN *----- "
            if ("application/x-pkcs12".equalsIgnoreCase(privateKeyType)) {

                //downloadedPK is "MIIKQAIBAzCCCfwGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCCe0EggnpMIIJ5TCCBhYGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCBgcEggYDMIIF"
                privateKeyContent = downloadedPK;
            }

            rawPrivateKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyContent);

            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpecPKCS8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyContent));
            PrivateKey privateRsaKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpecPKCS8);
```

But what is it that I get in java for downloadedPK

```
MIIKQAIBAzCCCfwGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCCe0EggnpMIIJ5TCCBhYGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCBgcEggYDMIIF
```

I got this error. Does it mean that I got the private key string in pkcs12 format? How can I do with this pkcs12 String?

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : version mismatch: (supported:     00, parsed:     03
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:251)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:390)
```

**Updated:**
I updated the code to do following:

```
1.Get certificate form Azure; print out its public key;
2.Get secrete form Azure; print out its secret.getValue();
3.Manually download pfx format file from Azure
4.Manually import above pfx file into Keystore;
5.readFromJKS for certification/public/private key
```

downloadedPK is **not** any of certificate/public/private key.

[image]

```
Output from certificate.getPublicKey()
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAriOYbRHHyMTtrGVkDDWr0coVcKqgXpPEG8iUTbUucl1TYNHsgNSfkWjofc/fQdvGhDE9e4nVL4Mh4wX6RVpn7gb5TnmYuOQ7pbCcZCwc4gfU80moj0nx6fSyXWyaoakBNkwInIAD8/wRfm3itx8NBO1orWV1XwDwtt3CbRAajQYpPt83ZNuIaO6uWXfJwM3qPMtmDwDmbK+fFyjfUQjB2vhwvEWpsZ1bp8A9Q5d8bBLqMlocyJuYtbpJtfgspbGsGwxbVQ1whnMyrDv/tcnob8EL85vlSN0Qzue3I+V6LnFOOlEtuFlfCjjmHZBYFwT2o3tn0hZpU6NHe+VycQYN2QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
2023-02-27:16:51:21.418 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO  com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential - Azure Identity => getToken() result for scopes [https://vault.azure.net/.default]: SUCCESS
2023-02-27:16:51:21.418 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO  com.azure.core.implementation.AccessTokenCache - Acquired a new access token.
getContentType = application/x-pkcs12
secret.getValue() = 
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

Begin readFromJKS

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQCuI5htEcfIxO2sZWQMNavRyhVw
qqBek8QbyJRNtS5yXVNg0eyA1J+RaOh9z99B28aEMT17idUvgyHjBfpFWmfuBvlOeZi45DulsJxk
LBziB9TzSaiPSfHp9LJdbJqhqQE2TAicgAPz/BF+beK3Hw0E7WitZXVfAPC23cJtEBqNBik+3zdk
24ho7q5Zd8nAzeo8y2YPAOZsr58XKN9RCMHa+HC8RamxnVunwD1Dl3xsEuoyWhzIm5i1ukm1+Cyl
sawbDFtVDXCGczKsO/+1yehvwQvzm+VI3RDO57cj5XoucU46US24WV8KOOYdkFgXBPaje2fSFmlT
o0d75XJxBg3ZAgMBAAECggEAE056/cy027uJpk1vdDMXI6FGE0G3mgTD/1iTqLHnvmI+dkOP9xCb
yGFbNWewlvqo3csfx+yWKDhfr23gO4Q0dZ1sUpkEp6sWOd6E2E5TvXOk1nxaJdjK62dnxxfdZQL5
0W1InyFKTuipf9zq/+Z/aQZxTpgrFSdjiMK5ZaIdb3kKjUvTl6qmJ+fmS1QE+7nj9jHujZTNyWr/
d0z8jsZIl25kKgIM/afAAxd5Pt2+kuN7IqoukoO5zTZie4skHQcmiA7r2GjcrLTzaRhSHyZtSp0g
ecbXWVA42ODXm5bE2WTwnqadTo+YSpG1j6/vjuZOkO9XZy8XlwKpvdZmXfHP6QKBgQDabVCordyL
tr9JIf+jwDxD9id9zGCTs1cJORA9lzXLw8V60q7n4M3RyU457EuiALdkfF2iWv05ITGwbeuJGkUL
LWMnPNOV/ibQ+dijGbjI99xefFJKR9zw/1CFSvHnvrCV63/v1OhBRyiFoGYuE2QW/5b/Fv27T29j
ujdOjl7gFwKBgQDMGAI64Q4ks2GPPbrMKwdWXYuSBy0ihJxFdM4nsEgYxQCFk68sXo9/VweHPWaU
SMHWP1jQgxmbFxlYUKjNQQn+LoIZRV6HHei9XtNt0mBPax/UeMqWaxDRoFHE9qyrKf/tPdy6pA/Y
IveRjc/swCClUl4FJSEJsCD6f8pRrPPHjwKBgFrqER6Ebz2/7NJ10j/ILc1j0YAs5y3TAbEXDUl1
fLC5ZaL/uklNap2dGnBFiB2ACtVKZnbDRI7Y4CO9PMIuKvrCA3k7eh3+UQ2+UItik2UitZimSmIc
kzvEKTGxxgpddoaQJQogJiO1iIpF/wHClHB2JdU7LpUeNRDfW1HZNGg1AoGBALamSeCdpsWrj4Tc
zr6HR5LANvch2v/IQ/5Y0WJtfahFLfldOOjxW2Sv4znh9lqAXpC5smcw3IqSeokx7k96hFHpF188
WKN9XduT8I2ZN737dcn1rAA/oxanbmZiCBdKiBKuSUrzJobcjEjD7C/Jpa2ucBwUpWOBL5JfKRY9
PRH7AoGAWlwe5M0xmxlgyKEKwbCOVjoDkTbEZ12VYNN6zbLNm5RfyGS7DS9bW/1UYghH3TAvI6N4
F8mLTZhKjF6jsdQPaaPxXcX46ED0Ke6oum8Uf7SlOKVIk7D4WyQvtxbKFoXHSwP5j9wzc36YJL1A
xG7JHnzBxGLqnEdKCMKWU49deAo=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAriOYbRHHyMTtrGVkDDWr0coVcKqgXpPEG8iUTbUucl1TYNHsgNSfkWjofc/fQdvGhDE9e4nVL4Mh4wX6RVpn7gb5TnmYuOQ7pbCcZCwc4gfU80moj0nx6fSyXWyaoakBNkwInIAD8/wRfm3itx8NBO1orWV1XwDwtt3CbRAajQYpPt83ZNuIaO6uWXfJwM3qPMtmDwDmbK+fFyjfUQjB2vhwvEWpsZ1bp8A9Q5d8bBLqMlocyJuYtbpJtfgspbGsGwxbVQ1whnMyrDv/tcnob8EL85vlSN0Qzue3I+V6LnFOOlEtuFlfCjjmHZBYFwT2o3tn0hZpU6NHe+VycQYN2QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE KEY-----
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
-----END CERTIFICATE KEY-----

Done readFromJKS
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be a proper P12 keystore format (the same thing you can generate using Java Keytool if you are generating a keystore from the command line).

This should help you see how it can be converted to certificate:
https://github.com/nagyesta/lowkey-vault/blob/0c3fde5ad7f433d72ded05f6d3e55a3bb55aec18/lowkey-vault-docker/src/test/java/com/github/nagyesta/lowkeyvault/steps/CertificateStepDefAssertion.java#L125-L139

Also, these lines can be helpful showing how I am parsing supposedly the same thing during import: https://github.com/nagyesta/lowkey-vault/blob/0c3fde5ad7f433d72ded05f6d3e55a3bb55aec18/lowkey-vault-app/src/main/java/com/github/nagyesta/lowkeyvault/service/certificate/impl/CertContentType.java#L44-L69

When you download the certificate store contents as a secret, it should use a blank password based on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/how-to-export-certificate?tabs=azure-cli#export-stored-certificates (I think they mean blank as in "" and not null as null would be problematic on Java: [Sun Java KeyManagerFactory and null passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814048/sun-java-keymanagerfactory-and-null-passwords))

Confirmed with an experiment. If the `String value` contains the content downloaded using the secret client, in case of a PFX, then this code opens the key store and iterates through the certificate aliases in it. Of course you would need to make it nice, including error handling etc.

```
final byte[] p12binary = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(value);
final KeyStore p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
p12.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(p12binary), "".toCharArray());
for (final Iterator<String> it = p12.aliases().asIterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    final String alias = it.next();
    System.out.println(alias);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think there might be issue with the String downloadedPK = secret.getValue();  from Azure. It is not any of certificate/public/private key.

Comment: In my example, I have been using it with a self-signed cert I generated earlier and it contained a certificate and a private key. I hope it helps!